# How to compare key with sum of array of objects' keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

I have arrays of objects `ob1` and `ob2` and I want to check whether the total quantity `total` of each object is be equal with the sum of the `qty`s of the objects in the `info` array.

if `total = sum(info.qty)` for all objects then return an empty array otherwise return the objects with the invalid `total` fields.

My attempt so far:

```
function checktotal(ob1) {
    var result = ob1.forEach(e => {
     if (e.info.length > 0) {
        var sum = e.info.reduce((a, {qty}) => a + qty, 0);
       if (sum !== e.total) {
        return "total qty not matches with info total qty,"+e
       }
   })     
}

var ob1 = [
 {id:1, total: 2, info:[{idx:1, qty:1},{idx: 2, qty: 2}] },
 {id:2, total:1, info: [{idx:1, qty:1}] };
];
var ob2 = [
 {id:1, total: 1, info:[{idx:1, qty:1}] },
 {id:2, total:4, info: [{idx:1, qty:2},{idx: 2, qty: 2}] };
];
```

Expected Output:

```
checktotal(ob1); // should return [{id:1, total:2, info:[{idx:1, qty:1}, {idx:2, qty:2}]}]
checktotal(ob2); // should return []
```

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: What happens if more than one entry does not match the `total` value? What would be the result when `ob1[1].total === 2`?

Comment: You have several syntax errors in your code, perhaps from copying and pasting. For instance, there's a missing end bracket `}` for the `if(e.info.length > 0) {` block. It would be helpful if you created a [mre] using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in a page in the editor toolbar), using `console.log` to show results, then click Run to make sure there are no errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can `filter` the records by comparing total and getting total of info `qty` by making use of `reduce()`. Here is a working example

```js
var ob1 =[
 {id:1, total: 2, info:[{idx:1, qty:1},{idx: 2, qty: 2}] },
 {id:2, total:1, info: [{idx:1, qty:1}]}
];

var result = ob1.filter(k=>k.total!=k.info.reduce((a, {qty})=>a+qty,0));

console.log(result);
```

I hope this will lead you towards right direction.

Comment: @Andreas Updated my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Working commented example:

```js
// finds total sum of qtys in info array
function totalSum(infoArray) {
  return infoArray.reduce((acc, info) => acc + info.qty, 0);
}

// returns items with incorrect totals
function checkTotal(itemArray) {
  return itemArray.filter(item => item.total !== totalSum(item.info));
}

let ob1 = [
  {id:1, total:2, info:[{idx:1, qty:1}, {idx:2, qty:2}]}, // incorrect total
  {id:2, total:1, info:[{idx:1, qty:1}]}, // correct total
];

let ob2 = [
  {id:1, total:1, info:[{idx:1, qty:1}]}, // correct total
  {id:2, total:4, info:[{idx:1, qty:2}, {idx: 2, qty: 2}]}, // correct total
];

console.log(checkTotal(ob1)); // returns 1st item
console.log(checkTotal(ob2)); // returns empty array
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a function that returns the subset of objects from an input array of objects for which the total amount in `total` does not equal the sum of the amounts in `qty` in the objects inside `info`.

You can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the array of mismatching objects, and the condition to check the sum makes use of [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Below is a working example.

Please note that unlike what you requested, the call on the first array of objects returns an array that contains the culprit object, instead of just the object itself.

```js
function checkTotal(data) {
    return data.filter(({ total, info }) => (
        total !== info.reduce((acc, { qty }) => (acc + qty), 0)
    ));
}

var ob1 = [
    { id: 1, total: 2, info: [{ idx: 1, qty: 1 }, { idx: 2, qty: 2 }] },
    { id: 2, total: 1, info: [{ idx: 1, qty: 1 }] }
];
var ob2 = [
    { id: 1, total: 1, info: [{ idx: 1, qty: 1 }] },
    { id: 2, total: 4, info: [{ idx: 1, qty: 2 }, { idx: 2, qty: 2}] }
];

console.log('ob1', checkTotal(ob1));
console.log('ob2', checkTotal(ob2));
```